# and then it redirects to /adfs/oauth2/authorize/wia?

Tags: adal, adfs3.0

I am doing the authz code grant flow on ADFSv3.

When I do AcquireToken, the usual html web browser authentication prompt is initiated, but for some reason it redirects to the following endpoint `/adfs/oauth2/authorize/wia?` showing the windows integrated login box.

Question:

is this some sort of ntml/sso thing ADFS provides here?

is it possible to get rid of the initial html web browser and instead directly show the windows login box, it looks kind of like a split personality with 2 authentication prompts (1 disabled, 1 enabled).

Answer (score 2):

Is the client computer from which you're doing the AcquireToken flow domain-joined? It's likely not. It looks like it is attempting windows integrated authentication (Kerberos) and falling back to NTLM (Windows credential collection dialog you're seeing).

You can configure the authentication methods offered by ADFS using the ADFS Global Authentication policy (i.e. Set/Get-AdfsGlobalAuthenticationPolicy PowerShell cmdlets) or via the Authentication Policies node in the MMC snap-in. Ensure that you have 'Forms Authentication' enabled for both intranet and extranet locations in the global authentication policy in order to use web-based credential collection experience. You can also choose to turn off Windows Integrated Authentication in the global authentication policy, if you'd like.

If both forms authentication and WIA are enabled for the intranet location, ADFS will prefer to use WIA if the client's user agent/browser is WIA-capable. You can see a list of WIA-capable user agents via the Get-AdfsProperties cmdlets (look for the WIACapableUserAgents setting). Typically browsers like IE are capable of WIA. For user agents that are not on this list, ADFS will automatically fall back to using forms authentication.

Comment: hi, it reverts to ntml as I am not in the domain yes, my question was how can we get rid of the browser in the background and only show the wia box or simply keep showing the browser (and not both as in this case). I believe this is an ADAL 'issue'. Why provide the wia prompt all of a sudden, when doing the authz code grant flow. yes oauth2.0 does not specify how the authentication scheme is done, but i was just surprised by the wia box and the user agent in the background (dimmed). cheers Allan